# Windows batch delete lines

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file, command-line

I want to delete the lines that containing a certain string except the first line(that contains the particular string that I want delete).

```
findstr /v MyString file.txt > newfile.txt
```

I used this code to delete but as you see this delete all string(also the first line).
How can I do?

For example, this is the first file (file.txt):

```
Anna;Mary;sylvia
1;345;100
23;34;45
Anna;Mary;sylvia
23;54;99
Anna;Mary;sylvia
10;23;34
```

Now I expect this (newfile.txt):

```
Anna;Mary;sylvia
1;345;100
23;34;45
23;54;99
10;23;34
```

**SOLUTION**

I found a solution to my problem.
Here this the piece of code:

```
set /p var=<file.txt
echo %var% >> newfile.txt
findstr /v MyString file.txt > newfile2.txt
type newfile2.txt >> newfile.txt 
del newfile2.txt
```

In the first two lines I take the header and write it on the newfile. In the third line I clear all rows with MyString and write the other lines on newfile2.txt and finally append the newfile2(with all lines) with newfile(where there is the header).

Comment: For clarification, please provide examples of what you find in `file.txt`, what you _expect_ to find in `newfile.txt`, and what you are _actually_ getting in `newfile.txt`.

Comment: ok, I edited it.

Comment: This is probably easier to do in PowerShell, but it can still be managed with `CMD` and `FINDSTR`; see [SS64 on `FINDSTR`](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) and [SS64 on `FINDSTR` across line breaks](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr-linebreaks.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
@Echo off
Set File=file.txt
Set NewFile=NewFile.txt

Set /P Header=<%File%
(Echo:%Header%
 Findstr /xlv /C:"%Header%" %File%
) > %NewFile%
```

A longer variant with some explanations, here getting the file to process via cmd line

```
:: Q:\Test\2017\08\23\OneHeader.cmd
@Echo off
:: Strip duplicates of the header (first line) from the File passed as argument.
:: creates a backup File with _bak appended to the name without extension

If "%~1" equ ""    (Echo No File name passed as argument & Pause & exit /B 1)
If not exist "%~1" (Echo File name %1 not found          & Pause & exit /B 1)
Set "File=%~1"
Set "FileBackup=%~dpn1_bak%~x1"
:: Read first line of File into variable Header 
Set /P Header=<"%File%"
Move /Y "%File%" "%FileBackup%" 2>NUL
:: write Header and old content stripped from all headers to output 
(Echo:%Header%
 Findstr /xlv /C:"%Header%" %FileBackup%
) > "%File%"
```

Comment: Please explain what your code does. Those who can understand it also could have written it themselves.